# How to write Japanese with LaTeX?

Tags: languages, cjk, japanese

I've recently started to use LaTeX but I've just encountered a problem, I tried searching it, although apparently no-one asked it before.

I'd like to write using Japanese input, but when I typeset, there can happen 3 things:

1. I get some error when compiling;
2. I get question marks where Japanese stuff should appear;
3. Nothing appears.

For example I had an example .tex file, compiled it and it worked, so I added some japanese in order to see "The author is [Japanese here]", but what I could see was "The author is [blank space]".

I've tried checking some guides, but I haven't found anything that could solve my problem (they are too old, or they don't talk about this at all).

Some minutes ago I tried compiling this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{CJKutf8}  
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}  
\usepackage[overlap, CJK]{ruby}  
\usepackage{CJKulem}  
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.2ex}  
\newenvironment{Japanese}{%  
\CJKfamily{min}%  
\CJKtilde  
\CJKnospace}{}  
\begin{document}  
\parskip 3ex  
\parindent 0pt  
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}  
\begin{Japanese}  
ねこ   
\end{Japanese}  
\end{CJK}  
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine but, still same problem, nothing appears when typeset, even if I should see "ねこ". There are many Linux guides, but I have a Mac and apparently, there aren't a lot around...

EDIT: A small add, if I get this to work, is the solution related to other asian languages such as Korean or Chinese?

Comment: @Leo Liu, @Nyiti, @Bob BeckettGuys, I found out that probably it's a matter of encoding. If I write 丸 (example) I'll get nothing like I said but if I write ¥›, it will appear properly on pdf! :|

Comment: It's testament to the quality of this site that when Googling 'japanese in latex', this is the first search result. (As opposed to some of the more questionable results which appear further down the list)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

## 1. XeLaTeX

For XeLaTeX, the document should be saved in UTF-8 encoding.

### 1.1. `xeCJK` package

I advice you to use XeLaTeX with package `xeCJK`. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho} % for \rmfamily
\setCJKsansfont{MS Gothic} % for \sffamily
\begin{document}

\section{日本語}
お早う

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

See manual of `xeCJK` and `fontspec` for more information.

Chinese and Korean work the same. In fact, `xeCJK` is originally designed for Chinese by Prof. 孙文昌.

`xeCJK`: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf
`fontspec`: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf

### 1.2. `zxjatype` package

`zxjatype` internally calls `xeCJK`, with some configurations for Japanese. You can also use `zxjafont` package to use some predefined fonts. It is easier to use compared to raw `xeCJK`. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}
\begin{document}

\section{日本語}
お早う

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

`zxjatype`: http://zrbabbler.sp.land.to/zxjatype.html

### 1.3. `bxjsclasses` with `zxjatype`

`bxjsclasses` bundle provides some Japanese local classes. It can be used with different TeX engines.

```
\documentclass{bxjsarticle}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}

\begin{document}

\section{日本語}
お早う

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

## 2. LuaLaTeX

For LuaLaTeX, the document should be saved in UTF-8 encoding.

### 2.1. `luatexja-fontspec` package in `luatexja` bundle

`luatexja` bundle provides Japanese support for LuaTeX. A simple LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{MS Mincho} % \mcfamily
\setsansjfont{MS Gothic} % \gtfamily

\begin{document}
\section{日本語}

お早う

\textgt{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

### 2.2. `ltjsclasses` classes in `luatexja` bundle

`ltjsclasses` provides some Japanese document classes for convenience. An example:

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{MS Mincho} % \mcfamily
\setsansjfont{MS Gothic} % \gtfamily

\begin{document}

\section{日本語}

お早う

\textgt{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

## 3. upLaTeX + `ujclasses`

upLaTeX is a Japanese TeX format. It needs UTF-8 encoding.

An example:

```
\documentclass{ujarticle}

\begin{document}

\section{日本語}

お早う

\textgt{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

Compile with

> ```
> uplatex foo.tex
> dvipdfmx foo.dvi
> ```

## 4. pLaTeX + `jsclasses` (Relatively Old)

pLaTeX is a Japanese TeX format. **Documents should be saved in SJIS encoding**. Documentation in English is available [here](http://www.nihilist.org.uk/Home/English_Notes_on_pTex.pdf).

An example:

```
% SJIS encoding
\documentclass{jsarticle}

\begin{document}

\section{日本語}

お早う

\textgt{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

Compile with

> ```
> pdfplatex foo.tex
> ```

or

> ```
> platex foo.tex
> dvipdfmx foo.dvi
> ```

## 5. `CJK` package (Obsolete)

Older `CJK` package is still useful. It works well with PDFLaTeX and LaTeX (Dvips, dvipdfmx). If the document has only a few wide characters, `CJK` package may be a reasonable choice with better compatibility.

Be sure you have installed the proper CJK fonts for `CJK` package. Typically, this is not done. TeX Live and MiKTeX have a [`wadalab` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wadalab), install it when necessary. (Also [`ipaex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ipaex) and [`ipaex-type1`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ipaex-type1)) Then you can use:

```
% UTF-8 encoding
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}

\section{日本語}
お早う

{\CJKfamily{goth} こんにちわ}

\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

See `$TEXMF/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/c70*.fd`, `$TEXMF/tex/latex/cjk/contrib/wadalab/c70*.fd`, etc. for pre-installed CJK font families. Frankly speaking, these free Type1 CJK fonts are not very good. It is better to install the fonts yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give this all a try... It might take some time though, due to my noobness :) I'll let you know.

Comment: If we use XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX, do we lose features provided by `microtype`?

Comment: @Damien: Develop version of `microtype` partly support XeTeX.

Comment: I can't understand how to install the wadalab package. I spent the two hours trying to install at least one of those packages, but when I came to convert .afm files to .tfm files using a not-to-be-found encoding file I came to the conclusion that I would have never been able to do such thing...

I'd use Xelatex, but my nearly-finished document uses a big quantity of packages (inputenc, babel, tocbibind, makeidx, mathptmx, geometry, lipsum, fancyhdr, chngcntr, url, footmisc, etoolbox) which, I'd have to install again. How is this possible that I can't just download a package and write kanji?

Comment: @user46007: No, you don't need to install these packages yourself. You can install a full version of TeX Live or MiKTeX and start working. No `.afm` to `.tfm` conversion is needed at all. You may ask a local expert nearby to deal with your thesis.

Comment: I installed TeXlive. I switched the LaTex and PdfLaTeX directory in the TeXstudio configuration panel. Yet if I use the example code I find in the CJK documentation it won't work. If i try to use the wadalab package latex doesn't find it. I get the most various errors when I try to compile the given code :(

Comment: @user46007: I've no idea. I use TeX Live 2013 (updated with TeX Live Manager), and all these code was tested.

Comment: @user46007: Run TeX Live Manager to update all the pacakges and DON'T put any files you download yourself. I don't recommend `CJK` package at all. Anyway, a `CJK` solution will be easy if you only use one or two CJK font family like `min`, `mj`.

Comment: @user46007: And don't use those example code from CJK document. They are quite outdated. Use my code.

Comment: In the end I found a way to not use them in my document, and brutally solved the problem that way. I don't think it's a matter of upgrade anyway: I downloaded TeX Live two days ago.

Comment: with `xeCJK` and `XeLaTeX`, `\textbf` or `\bfseries` doesn't work. why?

Comment: @GreekFellows: You need to use a font family which does have a Bold variant, e.g. `Microsoft YaHei`. Otherwise you must set the actual font of bold series, or you mey use the `AutoFakeBold` option.

Comment: Not related to LaTeX, but it should really be こんにちは instead of こんいちわ

Comment: I had to use `\setCJKmainfont{PingFang SC}` on Mac OSX as a japanese character 勧(U+52E7) was rendering as letter F in a box. A good tip I read on another post is to use a WYSIWYG editor to verify the target font, make sure all the characters work and then update the CJK main font in the LaTeX header.

Comment: Method 1 works for me - on linux ubuntu I need to apt install fonts-takao-mincho and set the font to \setCJKmainfont{TakaoPMincho} otherwise some characters are missing.

Answer (score 45):

This blog post outlines Chinese-Japanese-Korean support in LaTeX: [link](http://latex-my.blogspot.com/2010/06/cjk-support-in-latex.html)

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}未練なく散も桜はさくら哉\end{CJK} \\
without regret \\
they fall and scatter\ldots \\
cherry blossoms

\end{document}
```

You can compile it with the `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` combo or with `pdflatex` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the site is loading so slow though :D I'll wait until it's done... Hopefully. :)

Comment: Sorry, it took quite some time, honestly I left it lol... I chose you because your example worked. :)

Comment: I hope it works out, good luck with your project!

Comment: Characters are working, I have some new problems sometimes (things like size, font choice, etc) but there is plenty of material... I might be able to solve it by myself :D

Comment: Note that this example only works on Ubuntu Quetzal if you install the package `latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab` (via http://blog.mindfall.net/?p=221).

Comment: Please don't use the default `min`, `goth` CJK fonts for Japanese. They are not professional. Instead use fonts provided by [ipaex-type1](https://ctan.org/pkg/ipaex-type1) package. In Ubuntu it is provided by `texlive-fonts-extra` package.

Answer (score 6):

You might also try XeteX with the [genzi.sty](http://kuniyoshi.fastmail.fm/xetex/) package, which is specifically for Japanese.

If you read Japanese well, Google "luajalayout" and "LuaTeX-ja."  A pdf sample of the output looks very good. It appears to require a separate installation from the standard LuaTeX, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

## 2020 Update

Thanks to a comment above from `eiennohito`, I've gotten a professional looking Japanese font working on Arch Linux with `pdflatex` (although it should work for other distros).

#### Necessary Packages

- `texlive-bin` (provides `pdflatex`)
- `texlive-fontsextra`

The latter should install (among others) the following file:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ipaex-type1/c70ipxm.fdx
```

This is the font we want. Now, in our `.tex` file, using this font is as simple as:

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}

\section{私の人生｝  % Works in section titles too.
田舎に派遣されました。

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

A normal run of `pdflatex` on this file should succeed, and the resulting `.pdf` should have nice, professionally looking Japanese text within.

**Note:** If you want other text effects like `\textbf`, use `ipmxa` instead.

## References

- https://ja.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Japanese#CJKutf8_package_with_pdfLaTeX
- https://ctan.org/pkg/ipaex-type1

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `babel`.  As of 2020, this translates strings such as “Table of Contents” and allows you to select many different styles of counters (such as Hirigana, Katakana, Iroha and more).

Mixing Japanese with other scripts, such as Arabic or Devanagari, and automatically selecting the correct language and font without language and tagging, is possible in `babel`, and not other packages.  In theory, the `translator` and `translations` packages support Japanese dictionaries and would automatically select them, but as of 2020, you would need to write them yourself.

It also has the advantage of allowing you to mix Japanese and Chinese in the same document, although if you do this, you unfortunately will need to turn off the feature that automatically changes the language when it sees characters from a CJK script.  The Original Sin of the Unicode Consortium was thinking that 16 bits would be enough forever if they just forced Japan to share the same codepoints as China and Korea.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK TC}
\begin{document}

\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる

\bigskip

And you can also use Latin characters within your Japanese document.

\bigskip

\begin{verbatim}
このテキストは、別のフォントを持つことになります

This is a verbatim environment using a monospaced font.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]