# miktex can't find udmj.cfg

Tags: miktex, cjk

I'm trying very hard to compile the minimal document in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex/15528#15528) example. I just want to use CJK on my Windows install of Miktex and it always fails with this message:

```
miktex-makemf: The udmj source file could not be found.
Running hbf2gf.exe...

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)

Couldn't find `udmj.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font udmj67.

! Font C70/min/m/n/10/67=udmj67 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not f
ound.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.7 \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}µ£¬
                             t+¦pü¬püÅµòúpééµí£pü»püòpüÅpéësôë\end{CJK} \\
?
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problem with MiKTeX's `cjk-fonts` package. Unicode Japanese fonts for `wadalab` are missing.

In MiKTeX now, you can only use `C42` and `C52` font encoding for `wadalab` fonts, say, use

```
\begin{CJK}{JISdnp}{min}
```

or

```
\begin{CJK}{JIS2dnp}{min}
```

*with proper input encoding* will work. It is really not enough, I think.

---

An alternative is to use `xeCJK` with XeLaTeX. For example,

```
% UTF-8 Encoding, compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho} % for \rmfamily
\begin{document}
おはよう
\end{document}
```

Comment: already did that

Comment: @Nate: Then try to refresh FNDB (font name database) in MiKTeX Options. It seems that there are some problem with your installation.

Comment: did that, still nothing. I've never had installation problems of any sort before...

Comment: @Nate: Hmm... I use TeX Live. After checking on MiKTeX, I'm sure that in MiKTeX `wadalab` fonts are not complete. This is a BUG of MiKTeX. I think you can [contact Christian Schenk](http://miktex.org/contact) for this problem. Anyway, there are other ways to use Japanese in TeX, see also [my previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex/15524#15524).

Comment: @Leo, @Nate Yes this is a bug in miktex. Nate sent a minimal example to the mailing list and for this example the complete "virtual font" layer (tfm in udmj + vf) from `mincho-0-12-20080306.tar.gz` are missing. The example works fine after I installed the missing file. Probably other fonts from wadalab are incomplete too. I will make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: how did you install the missing fonts?

Comment: @Nate: Well I put the missing files (see http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3412178&group_id=10783&atid=110783) in a local texmf (http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/localadditions.html#id552695) in the correct folder (`fonts\tfm\...`, `fonts\vf`...) and then updated the FNDB.

Comment: What does "with proper input encoding will work" mean?

Comment: @IanGregory: Say the [Japanese encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_encoding), I'm not familar with these encodings. In `CJK.txt`: ‘dnp’ implements the character order of the Dai Nippon Printing fonts and is only available for JIS and SJIS encoding.