# Trouble with Japanese characters

Tags: errors, cjk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [miktex can't find udmj.cfg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28973/miktex-cant-find-udmj-cfg)

I've tried to write japanese characters in LaTeX, but it generates errors, this is what I've done (realy, this is from this from this link [How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex))

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}未練なく散も桜はさくら哉\end{CJK} \\
without regret \\
they fall and scatter\ldots \\
cherry blossoms

\end{document}
```

this is the output:

```
! Font C70/min/m/n/10/67=udmj67 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not f
ound.
<to be read again>
relax
l.7 \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}æœª
ç·´ãªãæ•£ã‚‚æ¡œã¯ã•ãã‚‰å“‰\end{CJK} \\
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
! pdfTeX error (font): invalid font identifier.
\font@name ->\C70/min/m/n/10/67
l.7 \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}æœª
ç·´ãªãæ•£ã‚‚æ¡œã¯ã•ãã‚‰å“‰\end{CJK} \\
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5126 strings out of 494053
64712 string characters out of 3146185
143067 words of memory out of 3000000
8399 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
4238 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
34i,1n,21p,189b,859s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Yes you must install these Japanese fonts. Different TeX distributions have different CJK font packages pre-installed. I suggest XeTeX without `CJK` package.

Comment: If you use MiKTeX, see [my previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28978/2674); if you use TeX Live, just install `wadalab` package via TeX Live Manager.