# 'Metric (TFM) file not found' error when using kotex(CJK-based) package

Tags: fonts, miktex, cjk

I'm using the kotex package in order to write in Korean in MikTex, and I found out that an error occurs on certain letters.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[nonewtxmathopt]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{kotex}

\begin{document}

\section{가}
나
\begin{enumerate}
\item ㄷ
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

> Couldn't open `uwmj.cfg'
>
> No creation rule for font uwmj31. ! Font
>
> LUC/uhcmj/m/n/10.95/31=uwmj31 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM)
> file  not found.

The log is full of 'No creation rule for font uwmj31.', 'No creation rule for font NanumMyeongjo.' etc.

The error only occurs when it faces a single letter; in this case, 'ㄷ' is the cause.
The location of the letter doesn't matter.
I tried searching for uwmj31 and downloading it but I don't know where I can find it, and I don't know the manual installation procedure either.
The problem occuring here seems to be similar to the one in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28973/miktex-cant-find-udmj-cfg?rq=1), but I'm not 100% sure about it.

I've always had a similar problem, and now I decided it's time to learn how to solve this.
It seems like MikTex has some bugs related to CJk fonts, and one solution would be just discarding MikTex and using TexLive, but I wish I can keep using MikTex for now.

Comment: I haven't the time yet to check, but try the install the files from the uhc-package: http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/uhc.tar.xz

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, but could you tell me how to install it? I searched for manual installation and found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows but it doesn't seem to fit in any category listed there.

Comment: It just looked like a normal compressed file so I just copied & pasted the contents into MikTex directory, but the result is the same. Not sure if I have to do configure something.

Comment: Don't put local things in the main miktex tree. Create your own texmf-tree and add it as a local root with miktex settings.

Comment: I just tried: unpack the uhc.tar.xz somewhere outside miktex, e.g.in a folder uhc. Then add the root folder as new root in miktex settings (the fonts folder should be the first subfolder). Add `\pdfmapfile{=umj.map}` to your document or add the map via updmap.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, it works now. Is there another solution which just uses MikTex package manager? I think it would be cleaner since I don't have to use a folder configured outside of MikTex installation. Also, why wouldn't you make an answer explaining the cause of the error etc. briefly so that I'd choose it as an answer?

Comment: There is no miktex package. You could make a bug report. Perhaps it then will get added.