# Myanmar (Burmese) line breaking with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, languages

I am having trouble getting Myanmar text to break at the end of lines properly.
The previous question [How do I wrap text that doesn't use SPACE character to segment word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38246/how-do-i-wrap-text-that-doesnt-use-space-character-to-segment-word) would appear to solve my problem. However, it is not working for me.

I am on Linux Mint. XeTeX version is 0.9995.

Here is what my document looks like *(font source: [Padauk SIL Font](http://www.sil.org/computing/catalog/show_software.asp?id=118))*:

```
\documentclass{article} % save as utf-8, run with xelatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 0.1pt

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Script=Myanmar]{Padauk}
လၢထံးလၢသီန့ၣ်ယွၤတ့လီၤမူခိၣ်ဒီးဟီၣ်ခိၣ်လီၤ ... (multiple paragraphs of text)
\end{document}
```

Running this through XeLaTeX, I get an error: `Undefined control sequence \XeTeXlinebreaklocale`, etc.. It appears that the compiler knows nothing about the `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` - do I need to include some additional package?
If I remove the `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` and `\XeTeXlinebreakskip` lines, my document compiles very nicely... with Myanmar text breaking only on spaces (but, unfortunately, not even on zero width spaces).

So, the basic question is, what am I doing wrong here. How do I get the 'my' line breaking local to work? OR How do I get XeLaTeX to break lines on zero width spaces? OR What is the correct way to typeset Myanmar text?

Note: This is actually not Myanmar, it's Sgaw Karen - which is implemented in Unicode as a subset of Myanmar. It's rules are much simpler than Myanmar: a line may break directly before a set of 25 characters. Is there an easy way to do that? If so, that would be the very best solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  The post you're linking to mentions `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`, with an `e` at the end. Is that the issue? (I can't test because I don't have the font Padauk.)

Comment: No, that's not it. Sorry about the typo though.

Comment: @BenSharon When responding to another user's comment, don't forget to address them with `@username` so that they'll get a notification. Please edit your question to get rid of the typo.

Comment: @BenSharon The most recent version of XeTeX is .9998. But this behaviour seems to depend on the font. Have you tried putting `\sloppy` in your document?  That seems to solve the problem for me.

Comment: This is 'works for me' with XeTeX 0.99992: without further information I suspect it needs a binary update (so off-topic).