# Japanese Problem using MacTeX 2011

Tags: mactex, xecjk

The XeLaTeX Japanese examples I find on TeX.sx seem to have this issue in common on my system. I'm running MacTeX 2011, fully updated at the time of writing. The following sample

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\begin{document}

\ruby{学}{がく}\ruby{生}{せい}

\end{document}
```

gives me this output

[image]

I checked Font Book, and the font in the example is present (this happens whatever font I try). In an ideal world I'd like to use Japanese with furigana (ruby text). Is there something wrong with my code, or something not quite right with MacTeX on this system?

Comment: I have MacTeX2011 as well on one of my computers (MacOSX 10.7.2), and the example you provide compiles fine. (It's "gaku-sen", right?) I do get the following message in the log file: "Could not resolve font Hiragino Mincho Pro/I (it probably doesn't exist)." There seem to be no problems with the regular, bold, and bold-italic variants. You may want to check if the Hiragino Mincho Pro font you have is up-to-date.

Comment: I have MacTeX 2011 and your MWE compiles fine on my system.

Comment: @Mico: The log file indicates no issues, and everything is up to date. Any ideas what's going on? Could it be a document encoding issue?

Comment: Damn it, it was a document encoding issue...

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe, but check [How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex) :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Seems not a dupe, since none of the answers addressed encoding.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Ah ok. I'm not very expert at LaTeX so I thought of giving you the link... :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Thanks for pointing me to it though. I'm not an expert either!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an encoding issue. Tell TeXShop to use unicode, either through the preferences or a TeXShop directive shown in the following:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\renewcommand\rubysep{0.1ex}

\begin{document}

\ruby{学}{がく}\ruby{生}{せい}

\end{document}
```

I've also changed the value of `\rubysep` to make the spacing a little better.

[image]