# Typesetting bopomofo (zhuyinfuhao) on right side of Chinese characters with ruby

Tags: fonts, cjk, chinese

I am writing a document mostly in English with a few Chinese examples. I would like to be able to typeset the Chinese characters with bopomofo (zhuyinfuhao) annotations to the *right* side of the character, e.g., [sample image of bopomofo to right](https://www.omniglot.com/images/langsamples/udhr_zhuyin1.gif), rather than the top/bottom, which I can already do using the ruby package. Is there a way to do this? I'm currently using LaTeX, but would be open to XeTeX, etc., if necessary.

Here's a MWE I can compile using `pdflatex`, which gets the bopomofo characters on top of the Chinese characters:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}
\newcommand{\cjktext}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bkai}#1\end{CJK}}
\usepackage[overlap, CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.5}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{0ex}

\begin{document}

\cjktext{\ruby{媽}{ㄇㄚ}}
\cjktext{\ruby{麻}{ㄇㄚ\'{}}}
\cjktext{\ruby{馬}{ㄇㄚ\v{}}}
\cjktext{\ruby{罵}{ㄇㄚ\`{}}}

\end{document}
```

The output with the bopomofo on top looks like this (the tone diacritics aren't quite where they should be, but this is the best I could do):

[image: output of MWE code]

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

A comment:

Some fonts already contain the bopo, like `HanWangKaiMediumChuIn`:

[image: bopomofo font]

but that means using `fontspec` and compiling with xelatex.

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\sampletext{了亶他件}

\setromanfont{HanWangKaiMediumChuIn}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample}
\huge
\sampletext
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to use TikZ: see [Typesetting furigana above and below original text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95729/typesetting-furigana-above-and-below-original-text) and alter `below` to `right`.

I think there is also a ruby solution - I will search for it.

---

Edited to add:

A tabular within a tabular also works.

[image: tabular]

Code

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fcjk{Noto Sans TC Regular}

\newcommand\fvside[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
\Huge #1 & #2\\%
\end{tabular}}%

\newcommand\fvover[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}%@{}
#1\\
#2\\
\end{tabular}}

\newcommand\fbpmf[3]{%
\fvside{#1}{\fvover{#2}{#3}}%
}

%adjust padding
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.2em}

\begin{document}
\fcjk
\fvside{另}{\fvover{ㄎ}{ㄚ}}
\fvside{剭}{\fvover{ㄎ}{ㄚ}}
\fvside{俜}{\fvover{ㄎ}{ㄚ}}
\fbpmf{四}{ㄎ}{ㄚ}
\end{document}
```