# How to use normal letter spacing in ruby/furigana?

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

See the following example, adapted from [Typesetting furigana above and below original text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95729/typesetting-furigana-above-and-below-original-text)

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage{setspace}

%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defaultrubysep}{0.25ex}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{\defaultrubysep}
\newcommand{\english}{}
\renewcommand{\english}{-3.2ex}
\newlength{\kanji@kana@no@nagasa}
\newcommand{\eruby}[3]{%
    %% save the current baselinestretch
    %% and reset value to "1"
    \let\oldbaselinestretch=\baselinestretch%
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
    \large\normalsize%
    \ruby{#1}{#2}%
    %% reassign \rubysep to allow furigana below
    \renewcommand{\rubysep}{\english}%
    %% measure the width of the first argument
    %% move to the left by that distance
    \settowidth{\kanji@kana@no@nagasa}{#1}%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr-\kanji@kana@no@nagasa\relax}%
    \ruby{\phantom{#1}}{#3}%
    %% restore the original \rubysep and \ baselinestretch
    \renewcommand{\rubysep}{\defaultrubysep}%
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\oldbaselinestretch}
    \large\normalsize%
}
\makeatother
%%


\begin{document}
\eruby{たんぼの}{Japanese}{Ruby}
\end{document}
```

This produces output like

[image]

Now, I want to use "ruby" for Latin characters (with CJK characters only in the main text), so I don't want this huge spacing between letters. Is there a way to get the normal spacing in the ruby text?

Using something like `\eruby{たんぼの}{\textsf{Japanese}}{\textsf{Ruby}}` gives normal spacing in the sans-serif font, but the same does not work for `\textrm`. Nor does defining `\newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Latin Modern Roman}` followed by using `{\latinfont Japanese}` etc. work.