# \markboth{}{} and CJK

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, cjk

I'm writing a Japanese dictionary using the `CJKutf8` package in LaTeX.
I wrote a few macros to make entries and everything works fine except 
setting headers with `fancyhdr`.

Using a macro:

```
\newcommand{\J}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}#1\end{CJK}}
```

I type Japanese in Unicode, but in

```
\markboth{\J{#1}}{\J{#1}}
```

it doesn't compile and strange errors occur.

This is a working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fix2col}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\rightmark\ -- \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\newcommand{\J}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}#1\end{CJK}}
\newcommand{\E}[4]{\hangpara{3em}{1}\textbf{\J{#2・}}\J{#1}\ #3\ \textit{#4}\J{\markboth{#2}{#2}\cleardoublepage\par}}
\begin{document}
\E{愛}{あい}{miłość}{cn}
\E{青い}{あおい}{niebieski; \emph{rz.} zielony}{ia}
\E{青信号}{あおしんごう}{zielone światło na sygnalizatorze}{mn}
\end{document}
```

Of course I don't want to make every entry on a separate page so when I remove 
\cleardoublepage it it does not compile.

How can I make a header with Japanese words in it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces and leave a blank line before them, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, you may see these error:

> ```
> name = cyberb53, rootname = cyberb, pointsize = 53
> mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
> ```
>
> ...

In fact, the TeX file is fine, but you don't have proper fonts installed for `CJK` bundle.

The simplest solution is to change

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}
```

to

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
```

And note that `song` CJKfamily is actually for Chinese rather than Japanese.

There are also many other solutions and I won't explain much. See also
[How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex)