# What packages are required for "setmainfont" and "setCJKmainfont"?

Tags: fonts, cjk, xecjk

I've searched for this extensively but couldn't find anything that could help me, but if you know of some previous question that might help, feel free to point me to it.

I have a document with Japanese characters and Latin characters. I'd like to make it clear that it used to work fine, I was able to see both set of glyphs. I left it alone for some time and when I re-took the document and typeset it, the Japanese glyphs disappeared. It worked everything except for the Japanese characters that were not printed. So I tried other packages but nothing worked.

Finally I tried setting two fonts, one for the Japanese part and one for the Latin characters. The reason behind this is that I need some words to be in italic and some to be Small Caps (for the Latin characters) since I failed to find a single font that supported Japanese and these two things as well.

However if I try to write:

`\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}`

I get this:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \selectfont has changed.
Latex Error: ...tex:37 LaTeX Error: Environment CJK undefined.
Latex Error: ...tex:175 LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{CJK}.
```

So my question is: Is there a font that might support all of that? Alternatively, what packages are required for me so that I can set two fonts and so that Latex automatically recognizes when to use each? I'd prefer a minimal approach over huge preamble codes to set this up.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec} % I was experimenting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\pagestyle{empty}

%\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
%\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\begin{document}

 Regular, \emph{italic} text, but also in \textsc{small caps}. And now for some 日本語 $\leftarrow$ Japanese.

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

> [image]

Comment: Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/)? It seems that your code is wrong. `xeCJK` package does not provide `CJK` environment.

Comment: And this question might help: [How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/)

Comment: BTW, `Hiragino Mincho Pro` is just fine for Japanese. It is a high quality font.

Comment: @LeoLiu I used both `xeCJK` and `CJKutf8`. I added a MWE since my real code is too big. I'll leave all of the packages I'm using so that if some conflict with each other you can tell me (I don't know that). :D

Comment: @LeoLiu By the way, I asked that very question you linked to. But that doesn't help me anymore. I guess something changed in the packages? I don't know. :|

Comment: It is not possible to use both `CJKutf8` and `xeCJK`, while `\setCJKmainfont` is provided by `xeCJK` and XeLaTeX is required.

Comment: @LeoLiu I tried one and the other first but well... :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. Do not use `CJK` or `CJKutf8` package. XeLaTeX is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\begin{document}

Regular, \emph{italic} text, but also in \textsc{small caps}.
And now for some 日本語 $\leftarrow$ Japanese.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably it wasn't actually using Xelatex... Thanks for the help!