# CJK inside a math environment

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fontspec, cjk

I'm trying to display CJK characters as part of math formulae in XeLaTeX, and it's not working well. I've tried a number of options, and all have failed:

- Defining a `\jp` font command via `fontspec` and then using `\text{\jp{character}}`. This gives me an undefined control sequence error.
- Using `fontspec`'s `\setmathfont`. This also gives me an undefined control sequence error.
- Using the `unicode-math` package with `\setmathfont[range="4E00-"2FA1F]{font}` - depending on the range, CJK characters either still display as the 'unavailable character' box or simply disappear

A minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\jp{TakaoPGothic}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range="96E2]{TakaoPGothic} % the code for this particular character
\setmathfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}

$離$
\jp{離}

\end{document}
```

This produces a missing-character box on the first line, and rightly outputs 離 on the second.

Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, you should not use `unicode-math` package to specify the font of non-predefined unicode block. The package is not intended to set CJK fonts for math formula. Moreover, you should not use `CMU Serif` as a math font, since it lacks most of the math glyphs and the opentype math table.

To typeset Japanese in XeTeX, it is preferred to use `xeCJK` package or `zxjatype` package based on `xeCJK`. See also [How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15524/2674).

Japanese in math formula is actually some text. In LaTeX, we use `\text` from `amsmath` package to typeset text in math. Say, you should use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAexMincho} % or some other Japanese font
\begin{document}

$\text{離}$

離

\end{document}
```

It is also possible to use Japanese characters in math formulas without `\text`, if you enable `CJKmath` option of `xeCJK`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKmath=true}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAexMincho} % or some other Japanese font
\begin{document}

$離$

離

\end{document}
```