# \fontfamily, \selectfont doesn't work for CJK font

Tags: fonts, cjk

I follow [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) to change CJK font for a certain part:

global: `FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB`

selective: `TpldKhangXiDictTrial`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB}

\begin{document}
字体：方正清刻本悦宋简体

{\fontfamily{TpldKhangXiDictTrial}\selectfont
字体：康熙字典体繁
}

\end{document}
```

It outputs `FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB` for both line

[image]

While this what I suppose to see:
[image]
[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: @koleygr I did try `\begin{myfont} text \end{myfont}` suggested at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/95054. It just .. didn't work either

Comment: try the XeLaTeX solution... (from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/37251#37251 using  the commands you see in the answer) Your code is LaTeX and not XeLaTeX... See the "A basic document will therefore look like the following:" code and use it

Comment: looking for chineeze XeLaTeX to create an answer

Comment: I didn't show your edit before posting the answer... alignment was probably a lost token and could be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `\setCJKfamilyfont` and `\CJKfamily`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB}
\setCJKfamilyfont{KhangXiDict}{TpldKhangXiDictTrial}
\begin{document}
字体：方正清刻本悦宋简体

{\CJKfamily{KhangXiDict}字体：康熙字典体繁}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\newCJKfontfamily`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB}
\newCJKfontfamily\KhangXiDict{TpldKhangXiDictTrial}
\begin{document}
字体：方正清刻本悦宋简体

{\KhangXiDict 字体：康熙字典体繁}
\end{document}
```

or:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB}
\newCJKfontfamily[KhangXi]\KhangXiDict{TpldKhangXiDictTrial}
\begin{document}
字体：方正清刻本悦宋简体

{\CJKfamily{KhangXi}字体：康熙字典体繁}
\end{document}
```

BTW, the `ctex` classes (`ctexart`, `ctexrep`, `ctexbook`, and `ctexbeamer`) are better choices if the main language of your document is Simplified Chinese. Documentations can be found here (if you can read Chinese):

https://ctan.org/pkg/ctex

https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk

Comment: @koleygr Yes, and using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in XeLaTeX can cause other problems. I deleted that line. Thank you!

Comment: welcome... delete this too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{FZQingKeBenYueSongS-R-GB}
\setCJKsansfont{TpldKhangXiDictTrial}
\begin{document}
字体：方正清刻本悦宋简体

\textsf{%
字体：康熙字典体繁
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try the second way

Comment: I changed it... But I also show your edit in the question... If alignment was the problem we can fix it.

Comment: Can you go back to the code that you said it works on your question? If yes add it in an answer or in your question and we will fix the alignment.

Comment: code added to question.

Comment: add a % exactly after '\textsf{' like my updated answer

Comment: It works. But I don't thinks it's a clean solution

Comment: I just found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex and so it is probably a duplicate and my way is the recomended

Comment: Ok... show the new answer... It is not the recomended +1 to the answer

Comment: Both the link and @ManTingFang suggest to use `\CJKfamily`

Comment: I saw and upvoted his answer.. the 1.1 XeLaTeX solution in the answers of the link above is like mine... But sure CJK comands are a better option... and I don't consider it a duplicate (because of the new XeLaTeX answer). This is what I said