# How can I submit my XeLaTex compiled paper in arXiv?

Tags: xetex, arxiv

I have some papers which are compiled by **XeLaTex** on the **Overleaf** platform. Now I would like to upload it in **arXiv** but it seems that **arXiv** does not accept **XeLaTex**. After compiling my paper on other compilers (Latex, PdfLatex) produces some error that I can not ignore. So is there any way to upload **XeLatex** complied paper on **arXiv**?

Comment: According to https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#other_formats you can't use Xe(La)TeX on arXiv. (See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542224/35864). You could try uploading the PDF, but they try to detect LaTeX-generated PDFs and force you to upload the source. There may be a way around that, though, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95080/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372154/35864 (the solutions are for pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, I couldn't find anything for XeLaTeX).

Comment: I have tried but these solutions did not work out for me.

Comment: I’m incredibly grateful for the hard work and the very useful service provided by the arXiv. However, this misfeature not only limits what we can do on their site, it prevents many other people from being able to upgrade to LuaLaTeX and modern packages. It’s responsible for a **lot** of questions on this site needing a second answer for PDFLaTeX.  And also for a lot of answers using legacy packages, and not using modern tools at all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! For those errors produced by using pdflatex that you cannot ignore, you can post a new question to ask for help.